# Cannot infer type arguments for HashSet<> error after spring upgrade

Tags: java, spring

I have upgrade from spring 4.2x to 5.3x, since then I'm getting a Cannot infer type arguments for HashSet<> error on following code.

```
public static final String SEARCH_REQ = "Search Request";
public static final String SEARCH_RES = "Search Response";

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static Set<String> SEARCH_ACTIONS = new HashSet<>(CollectionUtils.arrayToList(new String[] {
        SEARCH_REQ,
        SEARCH_RES
        }));
```

In Spring 4.2x CollectionUtils.arrayToList implemented as follows;

```
    public static List arrayToList(Object source) {
    return Arrays.asList(ObjectUtils.toObjectArray(source));
}
```

and in 5.3, as follows;

```
    public static List<?> arrayToList(@Nullable Object source) {
    return Arrays.asList(ObjectUtils.toObjectArray(source));
}
```

What would be the best way to resolve this issue?

EDIT : Thanks all, I went with `Arrays.asList` also can be fixed if I use `private static Set<?>` instead of `private static Set<String>` .

Comment: Why fixate on using `arrayToList`? There are many other ways to convert an array to list, like `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: In fact, you could have just wrote`Set.of(SEARCH_REQ, SEARCH_RES)`.

Comment: Rewrite initialization of set may be a better choice.